# Alter CSS3 animation loop when object leaves page

Tags: jquery, css, loops, animation

I have a CSS3-based animation with the "infinite" property set on the animation. You can see a demo at http://codepen.io/mprewitt/pen/Ezyuq

What I want to do is change the X position of the elements when they float off the top of the page, so that when they resume at the bottom of the page, they are in a new, random position. I thought I could do it with the jQuery "animationend" call-back, but it doesn't seem to work. Either my code is wrong, or the fact that the CSS animation is set to "infinite" means that it never ends (I thought maybe the end of the loop would be considered an "end", but maybe not).

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".ani-bubble" ).on( 'animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(e){

    // Change the item's 'left' property to a random value from -20% to 120%.
    var bubbleoffset = Math.floor((Math.random() * 140) - 19);
    $(this).css({ 'left': bubbleoffset+'%' });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gfqEL

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery.expr.filters.offscreen = function(el) {
  return (
      (el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) < 0 
      || (el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) < 0
      || (el.offsetLeft > window.innerWidth || el.offsetTop > window.innerHeight)
    );  
    };
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.ani-bubble').each(function(){
      if($(this).is(':offscreen')){
       var bubbleoffset = Math.floor((Math.random() * 140) - 19);
         $(this).css({ 'left': bubbleoffset+'%' }); 
      }
    });
  },50);
});
```

Comment: That's very close, but for some reason it doesn't work for the largest bubble (the red one in the example).

Comment: that happens because of its size, it is so big that after it's out of the top of the view port it immediately (less than 1 ms) shows up again from the bottom of the screen, therefor calculation on it is nearly impossible. so in order to get it to work, you need to change its size: (changed the size to 400px in the following example) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bCzku

Comment: OK, I resolved it by changing the keyframe destination to `top: -600px`, causing it to move further off the screen, which fixed the issue without changing the size of the object.